# Convert Datagrid or Gridview to excel with Page break

Tags: asp.net

I need to convert either an ASP.NET Datagrid or GridView to excel with a page-break that can be part of the target excel.
The first part to convert the grid control to excel is not that complex and fairly easy to do, but my problem is how to insert a page break to the excel file during the conversion process.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete code to Export GridView to Excel:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient; 

public partial class ExportGridView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = BindData();
            GridView1.DataBind(); 
        }
    }



    private string ConnectionString
    {

        get { return @"Server=localhost;Database=Northwind;
        Trusted_Connection=true"; }

    }



    private DataSet BindData()
    {
        // make the query 
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Categories";
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(query, myConnection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds, "Categories");
        return ds;

    }




    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;
        filename=FileName.xls");

        Response.Charset = "";

        // If you want the option to open the Excel file without saving than

        // comment out the line below

        // Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();

        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
        new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

        GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());

        Response.End();

    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

        // Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the
        specified ASP.NET server control at run time.

    }
}
```

Comment: Indent code with 4 space characters for it to be formatted like code and not like plain text.